# How do I use 'this' when converting code into an object?

Tags: javascript, oop

So I can reuse code in more than one place on a web page, I am converting it to Object Oriented Javascript.  The original code looks like this:

```
foo = 42;
function bar(a,b) {
    foo = a * foo + b;
}
...
bar(1,1)
```

I think I want it to look like this:

```
function Example() {
    this.foo = 42;
    this.bar = function() {
        this.foo = a * this.foo + b;
    }
}
var one = new Example();
var two = new Example();
...
one.bar(1,1);
two.bar(2,3);
```

However, I'm not sure I'm using 'this' correctly inside the nested function.  I've noticed that a few of the functions I'm going to convert are event handlers that already refer to 'this' in their body.  How do I distinguish the 'this' already in the event handler from the 'this' I want to use to access my local variables?

Comment: Remember that `this` depends only on how you call the function; it's dynamic, unless you cache or `bind` the `this` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local `var` in the Example class/function and then you can reference the appropriate `this` object.

```
function Example() {
   var self = this;
   this.foo = 42;
   this.bar = function() {
      self.foo = a * self.foo + b;
   }
}
```

Comment: @elclanrs face in palm. Javascript for you. lol I guess its just good practice to do so.

Comment: @elclanrs I'm declaring this the winner.  I'm not sure what the discussion is about, but I've re-read how creating an object creates a new namespace, and the "self" seems to handle my use case of bar being used as an exception handler (with "this" pointing to something other than the foo object).